# How to print Java Bean completely using reflection or any other utility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection, javabeans

I have an Java bean class `Person` containing 3 variables:

- name (String)
- age  (String)
- address (Object).

`Address` contains 3 variables:

- street
- door_no
- city

I would like to have a utility which should print all variables in `Person`.

By this I mean it should print `Person` & also the `Address` object contained in it.

I could create a hashmap and put the variable names & values using reflection and print key/value UI in JSP but the issue is I have to apply reflection for `Address` to add variable/value in the hashmap.

Is there a utility available to do this?

Comment: Isn't that what `#toString()` on these objects is supposed to do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

From documentation:

> A typical invocation for this method would look like:
>
> ```
>  public String toString() {
>    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
>  }
> ```

More details:

> This class enables a good and consistent toString() to be built for
>   any class or object. This class aims to simplify the process by:
>
> allowing field names handling all types consistently handling nulls
>   consistently outputting arrays and multi-dimensional arrays enabling
>   the detail level to be controlled for Objects and Collections handling
>   class hierarchies To use this class write code as follows:
>
> ```
>  public class Person {
>    String name;
>    int age;
>    boolean smoker;
>
>    ...
>
>    public String toString() {
>      return new ToStringBuilder(this).
>        append("name", name).
>        append("age", age).
>        append("smoker", smoker).
>        toString();
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, there is a method that uses reflection to determine the
>   fields to test. Because these fields are usually private, the method,
>   reflectionToString, uses AccessibleObject.setAccessible to change the
>   visibility of the fields. This will fail under a security manager,
>   unless the appropriate permissions are set up correctly. It is also
>   slower than testing explicitly.
>   A typical invocation for this method would look like:
>
> ```
>  public String toString() {
>    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
>  }
> ```

Comment: You can use ToStringBuilder outside your toString method. ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(otherObject)

Comment: you can use like this: `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(objectRetrieved)` exactly like Jeff explained

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth What if you have a list variable? List<String> hobbies; How can you set that toString?

Comment: The native List implementation present already a `toString()` that will output a string composed by each item's `toString()`. In `String` case something like `[Item1, Item2, Item3]` will be outputted, because it is using the `toString()` of `String` class. This means the output depends on the object class being stored by that list, so you will probably want to overwrite the `toString()` method of your classes to have a nice `List` output, and that could be done using the answer provided :)

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for Apache Commons [`ToStringBuilder#reflectionToString(Object)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 3):

You may find the Jackson **JSON serializer** useful for this purpose. The Jackson library may already be part of your stack. If not, find the required dependencies below.

```
private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER_SINGLETON = new ObjectMapper();
public static String toStringUsingJackson(final Object object) {
    try {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER_SINGLETON.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
        return String.valueOf(object);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> {"name":"John Doe","age":42}

Required **maven/gradle dependencies**:

- jackson-core, groupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.core
- jackson-databind, groupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.core

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `toString` method to print out whatever you want, or you can use Apache Commons `ToStringBuilder` http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html and its `reflectionToString` method. I don't believe this will recurse through the properties (like address for example), but if you want to see Address printed out with Street, Door No and City, use implement its `toString` method to print that information out.